# How to send variable using UDP datagram in linux?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp

I have a client and a server using UDP:
client.c:

```
#include<stdio.h> //printf
#include<string.h> //memset
#include<stdlib.h> //exit(0);
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>

#define SERVER "127.0.0.1"
#define BUFLEN 512  //Max length of buffer
#define PORT 8888   //The port on which to send data

void die(char *s)
{
    perror(s);
    exit(1);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in si_other;
    int s, i, slen=sizeof(si_other);
    char buf[BUFLEN];
    char message[BUFLEN];

    if ( (s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1)
    {
        die("socket");
    }

    memset((char *) &si_other, 0, sizeof(si_other));
    si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_other.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    if (inet_aton(SERVER , &si_other.sin_addr) == 0) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "inet_aton() failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter message : ");
        gets(message);

        //send the message
        if (sendto(s, message, strlen(message) , 0 , (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, slen)==-1)
        {
            die("sendto()");
        }

        //receive a reply and print it
        //clear the buffer by filling null, it might have previously received data
        memset(buf,'\0', BUFLEN);
        //try to receive some data, this is a blocking call
        if (recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen) == -1)
        {
            die("recvfrom()");
        }

        puts(buf);
    }

    close(s);
    return 0;
}
```

And of course my server:

```
#include<stdio.h> //printf
#include<string.h> //memset
#include<stdlib.h> //exit(0);
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>

#define BUFLEN 512  //Max length of buffer
#define PORT 8888   //The port on which to listen for incoming data

void die(char *s)
{
    perror(s);
    exit(1);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in si_me, si_other;

    int s, i, slen = sizeof(si_other) , recv_len;
    char buf[BUFLEN];

    //create a UDP socket
    if ((s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1)
    {
        die("socket");
    }

    // zero out the structure
    memset((char *) &si_me, 0, sizeof(si_me));

    si_me.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_me.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    si_me.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    //bind socket to port
    if( bind(s , (struct sockaddr*)&si_me, sizeof(si_me) ) == -1)
    {
        die("bind");
    }

    //keep listening for data
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Waiting for data...");
        fflush(stdout);
    memset(buf,'\0',BUFLEN);         
        //try to receive some data, this is a blocking call
        if ((recv_len = recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen)) == -1)
        {
            die("recvfrom()");
        }

        //print details of the client/peer and the data received
        printf("Received packet from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(si_other.sin_addr), ntohs(si_other.sin_port));
        printf("Data: %s\n" , buf);

        //now reply the client with the same data
        if (sendto(s, buf, recv_len, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &si_other, slen) == -1)
        {
            die("sendto()");
        }
    }

    close(s);
    return 0;
}
```

This code is working fine. But, I want to send just one message using UDP. If there are some variables for example : `int`, `int`, `string`, `int`. How to hide in to `buf` and the more important thing - How to receive the variables in server?

Comment: A couple of things: First don't use `gets`, it's dangerous and has been deprecated since the C99 standard and removed completely i the C11 standard, use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead. Secondly, the address structure length you provide to `recvfrom` can be modified, you need to set it every time you call the function.

Comment: As for your problem, if you want to send different data between the hosts, then you should probably invent some kind of protocol that tells you *what* kind of data is being sent. Using structures with a fixed header (including type of packet as well as the payload size) is one solution.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - could you give example (answer the question) how should look the most simple packet from client and received data in server.

Comment: @matkuz I thought your code already did that, 'This code is working fine'?

Comment: Its not all that good, TBH.  It has cargo-cult 'memset' in the assumption that transfers are always going to be text and that spending cycles on zeroing the receive buffer first is the only way of ensuring a null-terminated string:(

Comment: It would probably be helpful for you to punch "serialization" into a search engine or read the specifications of a few protocols that work over UDP such as TFTP.

Comment: You can use TPL library for quite easy packing/unpacking your data: https://troydhanson.github.io/tpl/

Comment: One easy way would be to encode your variables as ASCII text (e.g. using snprintf()) and then send that text using the code you already have.  The receiver would then need to parse the received ASCII text to extract the original values out again (e.g. using atoi()).  This would be one method of serialization, which as DavidSchwartz mentioned is what you're really asking about.  Serialization is the transformation of data into a series of bytes that can be placed into a UDP packet (or TCP stream), and its counterpart is deserialization, where the receiver reassembles them back into data.

Comment: on my system: ubuntu linux 14.04, the code is missing the statement: `#include <unistd.h>`  for the function: `close()`

Comment: the function: `gets()` was depreciated and is removed from the latest coding standard.  (your compiler should have told you this)  Suggest using `fgets()` instead of `gets()`.

Comment: the variable `slen` should be declared as: `socklen_t` rather than `int`

Comment: @MartinJames, the CPU cycles in the blocking call to recvfrom() will swamp any CPU cycles spent in the `memset()` function and when debugging, it is much easier to pick out the data when the buffer is pre-set to all NUL bytes

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability by us humans, please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because systems can differ in the details of their binary types (e.g., little-endian vs. big-endian, size of `int`s, padding of structures, null-pointer value, etc.) a protocol should be used that preserves the semantics of the types during transmission. This can be done either by using one of the well-known semantic-preserving protocols (e.g., XDR https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation, Google's protobuf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers) or by manually encoding the types into a portable format (e.g., converting all the types into strings at the sender and parsing them back into binary values at the receiver).

Comment: IMO: converting to/from ASCII is the easiest method (snprintf() and atoi().  However if you want to send different data types at different times, then the buffer[] should have first byte that is coded (probably by a enum that both the server and client use) that indicates which data is in the rest of buffer[]